# Vega lite: Add Total Column to Table Visual

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api

Here is my script:
https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUYGADhAE5QYC2GAdlPCAJICqAKiADQgDmpA9miIMAQgHlOIABYYoYAPqUIAR0xQK8AGwBGAAwaAvhwLEyFanQYBRAMKiAMpYAEAEVHX2XXgKFwQYidKyCsqq6nC6BkbgJuRUtPS+lgByAMqsAEopAGoSXoIi4lyB8ooqMmEAzAAsVQBMhsYkseYJIM4ACqyOALSOdgB0Ayn9ABL9ufz5vv5FMiUh5RjwWlpVGjoN0U1m8QwdXb3O-Zb9AOLjnpM+foVSc8FlaktwAJzrABybhNtxFokp7UsE28BQC91KoWe71qtQ2UW+pl+rX2PUcw1YFx4V1BsyCEMWy1qFQq9XhMR2fxAKWsTl6ADF+tZMXlrjM7niFk94C8AOwVL7kpFWWwOFxuDxYkGJZwpMEcx5hCICn4tPadVHo5nY6Wy3HzBXPLREknKxGq3wo3oDIajLVSkCWGVy-WQ5ardam5q7C3qw7HM52qYOp16h6u17aSKNM3eqk01EMpnAoOO3Xsl0E158z0U1osCUsqwh9NhzPaXQ5oX-QHJ66p52lrlwaE1Svmh2pDLZWtFtPFRuVGqk6Neyn5nu+FIYUiIY40LCY-v4ptVFtt2OWAFAy72qczucLhvLsLvI1wke5tUHFz+84TqnT2eWeeL8GcsIvF7vKNbGOUy19IM-TDGM957k+L5Hu+hq1AArLUVTrpSyRpJkOQ7kG4EHq+8rhrUbxaEhrTUrSjiJoG1xYc+h6hsezwvMSRFXhq-QYmBj7YVBBqErBLzDr+o6tDY9hOK47jsfu1E4RmTbvLB+gALqGCAiAAMZ8DQqnQHgoCKKQADWDAUAAHvQXC0OpYAAJY0Nw8CgAAnvZIAAGZWRgKBgAwhZcFADlEM8IA0HwlA2agEgQMZVk4AgIBQFZUAoIFEjxap+kxS5qBYBg+jKcZzluR5Xm+Aigkpf5gXBaFNDhVwkXRc5fCkO5lJQHwQhcCgEAAEYeQAgrZSXwDovkJUNvgSGAIUQDZ8BQKQmCjWlGVZTlXBYFp42gCQYDWbZyzycpJkJKAhWeQwS7QeVAUME1e3hblin6EAA

I would like to calculate and display the total of each line in the table:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"departement": "IUT", "group": "BO", "hetd_maquette": 6106},
      {"departement": "ECOLE DOCT", "group": "BO", "hetd_maquette": 106},
      {"departement": "ENSTRSV", "group": "BO", "hetd_maquette": 3442},
      {"departement": "DPT - L.L.S.H.", "group": "BO", "hetd_maquette": 11460},
      {"departement": "DPT - D.E.G.", "group": "BO", "hetd_maquette": 9608},
      {"departement": "ESPE", "group": "BO", "hetd_maquette": 8220},
      {"departement": "DPT - S.T.", "group": "BO", "hetd_maquette": 12332},
      {"departement": "SCE - F.C.", "group": "BO", "hetd_maquette": 973},
      {"departement": "ECOLE DOCT", "group": "EDS", "hetd_maquette": 106},
      {"departement": "DPT - S.T.", "group": "EDS", "hetd_maquette": 12332},
      {"departement": "DPT - L.L.S.H.", "group": "EDS", "hetd_maquette": 11460},
      {"departement": "DPT - D.E.G.", "group": "EDS", "hetd_maquette": 9616},
      {"departement": "SCE - F.C.", "group": "EDS", "hetd_maquette": 973},
      {"departement": "IUT", "group": "EDS", "hetd_maquette": 6110},
      {"departement": "ESPE", "group": "EDS", "hetd_maquette": 8244},
      {"departement": "ENSTRSV", "group": "EDS", "hetd_maquette": 3442},
      {"departement": "IUT", "group": "Serv.Ens.", "hetd_maquette": 4824},
      {"departement": "ESPE", "group": "Serv.Ens.", "hetd_maquette": 8120},
      {
        "departement": "DPT - D.E.G.",
        "group": "Serv.Ens.",
        "hetd_maquette": 9986
      },
      {
        "departement": "DPT - L.L.S.H.",
        "group": "Serv.Ens.",
        "hetd_maquette": 12524
      },
      {"departement": "ENSTRSV", "group": "Serv.Ens.", "hetd_maquette": 2961},
      {"departement": "SCE - F.C.", "group": "Serv.Ens.", "hetd_maquette": 933},
      {
        "departement": "DPT - S.T.",
        "group": "Serv.Ens.",
        "hetd_maquette": 12592
      },
      {"departement": "ECOLE DOCT", "group": "Serv.Ens.", "hetd_maquette": 85}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "hetd_maquette", "as": "Total"}],
      "groupby": ["group"]
    },
    {"calculate": "'Total'", "as": "TotalTitle"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "group",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"title": "", "ticks": false}
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "departement",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "orient": "top",
            "labelAngle": 0,
            "title": "",
            "domain": true,
            "ticks": false
          },
          "scale": {"padding": 15}
        },
        "text": {"field": "hetd_maquette", "type": "ordinal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "group",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {"title": "", "ticks": false}
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "TotalTitle",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "orient": "top",
            "labelAngle": 0,
            "title": "",
            "domain": true,
            "ticks": false
          },
          "scale": {"padding": 15}
        },
        "text": {"field": "Total", "type": "ordinal", "aggregate": "max"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```